# TextViews with utf-8 and special characters

Tags: java, android, html, utf-8, textview

StackOverflowers!

I load some text from a webpage. Everything works fine, and shows up in the TextViews. But, when the blogs on the webpage have some words with special characters like an: é or something. My Textview show characters like these: Á©..

Can anybody tell what I need to import, call or something like that to show everything tidy?

Thanks,

UPDATE 1 + 2:

```
TextView intro_text = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.item_intro);
intro_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(current_post.get_intro()));
```

current_post.get_intro() is the adres where the loaded text is. :-) Because I use a listview with many rows..

EDIT:

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {

        Log.v("Correct Load", "Starting ");
        URL u;
        InputStream is = null;
        DataInputStream dis;
        String s;

        try {
            Log.v("Connecting...");
            u = new URL("http://.......");
            is = u.openStream();
            dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
            Log.v("Connected");

            try {
                while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (s.contains("post_wrapper")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                            while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                                if (s.contains("post_intro")) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (s != null) {
                                s = dis.readLine();
                                Log.v("Intro", s); intro[i] = s.substring(s.indexOf("<p>") + 3, s.indexOf("</p>"));
                                Log.e("Intro", "Found intro:" + intro[i]);
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            System.out.println("Ouch - a MalformedURLException happened.");
            mue.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Oops- an IOException happened.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
            } catch (IOException {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the read/received part.

Comment: It's an encoding issue. Your TextViews don't use the same encoding of your WebService (hopefully it uses UTF-8).

Comment: I came across this issue recently too. It turns out the default encoding for HTTP requests and responses is ISO-8859-1, which encodes those special characters as single characters, but UTF-8 encodes them as double characters. So when UTF-8 is decoded as ISO-8859-1, you end up with multiple different characters (usually with the Á)

Comment: @Bob Malooga Yes, on top of my layout xml I have that line..

Comment: @Dan Temple What you mean exactly? What I need to do/try?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure how it applies to Android, but you could always try: `text.setTest(Html.fromHtml( URLDecoder.decode( stringVariable, "UTF-8"); ).toString());`

Comment: the reading from the page is wrong. post the code where you connect to that page.

Comment: in this Log : ´Log.i("TattlerMX intro", s);´  and this  ´Log.e("TattlerMX intro", "Gevonden intro:" + intro[i]);´ , you get bad string also ?

Comment: @DanTemple Can't get it without any errors :-(

Comment: @BobMalooga Thanks, but does not work.. Sorry,

Comment: @njzk2 Why? My code doen not fail or something.. Everything works fine.. But there is an: é or something in the text.. My log and textview shows an weird character like: Á©. Thanks

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 Yes I got the weird character in my log to.. (As I explain the comment above..) Thanks,

Comment: because when you read the text from the server you receive a byte stream, and you read it using the wrong encoding. (this is typical UTF-8 read in ISO-8859-1)

Comment: @njzk2 I changed my encoding in my XML from utf-8 to iso-8859-1, but still got some weird characters in my log and textview on my phone. Thanks,

Comment: that's not what I said. can you post the code where you read from the server?

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 Take it easy bro, look on top, below the line EDIT:. I post the code to read and receive the intro text.

Comment: @njzk2 Look on top.. Post my code below EDIT:. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the doc for `DataInputStream.readLine()`. It says `This method cannot be trusted to convert bytes to characters correctly.`. I suggest you use a BufferedReader with an InputStreamReader, and that you specify the encoding in the constructor of the ISR. See my answer.

Comment: @DanTemple Thanks for rescaling my text/code! :-)

Comment: @KD-21 Hah, no worries. I would try not to nest so much stuff if possible. It's a bit gnarly at the minute! XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
```

With

```
BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

Because `DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated and is discouraged for the following reason:

> This method cannot be trusted to convert bytes to characters correctly.

`BufferedReader` also has a `readLine`method, so the rest of your code should be pretty much unchanged.

Also, whenever you use `@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })` I strongly suggest that you be extra careful and make sure you can use the deprecated method despite the warning.

Answer (score 0):

tricky but worked for me: use `Html.fromHtml()` twice , I mean:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(your_html_text).toString()));
```

**EDIT** .

Your problem is not in this `TextView` because you are getting broken encoding even in your logcat, 
so you should know when exactly , the encoding is broken ; this `get_intro()` is returning a bad string, so you should show us , what is this `get_intro()` doing ? how is it taking the string ? from what ? you should share the code of this  `get_intro()` else nobody can help you...

Comment: Get the error: The method fromHtml(String) in the type Html is not applicable for the arguments (Spanned).

Comment: No error anymore, but I still have the weird Á and © characters.. instead of the: é.

Comment: when you log the string that you want to show, how you get it ? because if you have to verify that you have a problem in writing the string or in reading it . do `Log.i("test",your_html_text);` to see what you are getting as string ...

Comment: My log is not good too! The log shows the same weird characters.

Comment: then show us the code that you are using to read the text from the page or the web service ... your problem has nothing to do with the TextView ...

Comment: I Update me question on top! Thanks,